# Why doesn't setting the Foreground property of a RichEditBox to a LinearGradientBrush do anything?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, lineargradientbrush

I'm trying to set the foreground of a WinRT XAML RichEditBox to a linear gradient so that the text appears to fade to transparency at the top and bottom edges of the element. I've specified the LinearGradientBrush as follows:

```
<LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ForegroundColor" StartPoint="0.5,0" EndPoint="0.5,1">
    <GradientStop Color="#00424242" Offset="0.0"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF424242" Offset="0.1"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#FF424242" Offset="0.9"/>
    <GradientStop Color="#00424242" Offset="1.0"/>
</LinearGradientBrush>
```

For some reason, this doesn't do anything to the text. Even when I remove the opacity and change the color values to different primary colors, there is no change to the color of the text. The gradient should be specified correctly, because I can change the background of the RichEditBox to it and it displays as would be expected. The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.foreground.aspx) appears to suggest that this should be possible, but I can't seem to make it do anything at all to the foreground/text.

What am I doing wrong? How can I achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

There is [RichTextBox.Document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox.document%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property which contains your text. You should use [FlowDocument.Foreground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.flowdocument.foreground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to change text brush. But if document contains element which changes brush of child elements, it will override your default brush (`FlowDocument.Foreground`). For this case you can go through whole document recursively, find these elements and remove them or change their brush to default.

Comment: I'm not using a RichTextBox, but a RichEditBox in WinRT, and can't seem to find any references to FlowDocument. Does it have a different name in WinRT? If so, how would I access it? Thanks.